# I want to use tableview with multiple cells, once cell with multiple columns and 2 cells with one column only

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview, custom-cell

I have a tableview in which there are 3 separate cells, two cells with one column and once cell with 2 columns.
The indexPath should change for cells having 2 images in tableview cell.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: first cell with one column]

[image: cell 2 with 2 columns]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code to shoe differnt cells:- 


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.row = 0   // First Cell  
     {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“YourCell”, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCell
            return cell
     }
     else if indexPath.row = 1  // Second Cell 
     {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“YourCellWithTwoImages”, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCellWithTwoImages
            return cell
   }
    // Add Condtions for cells 
}
```